# request.getAttribute() return null

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I can`t understand one thing when i send request to get object by name from db,
it always return me null. I surf all sites try to fix it with session and etc. Nothing to work.
Any ideas?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn2YJ.png)
This is my Servlet class:

```
@WebServlet(value = "/display", name = "IndexServlet")
public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        try {
            if(!(request.getParameter("mysql")==null)) {
                MySQLRepository sql = new MySQLRepository();
                Headline object = sql.getByHeadline(request.getParameter("mysql"), DatabaseConnection.initDatabase());
                
                request.setAttribute("id", object.getId());
                request.setAttribute("headline", object.getHeadline());
                RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("out.jsp");
                requestDispatcher.forward(request,response);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is index.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MySQLSolrProject</title>
</head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<form action="out.jsp" method="get">
    <p>Headline:</p>
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="mysql">
    </label>
    <%--<br>
    <p>Full text:</p>
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="solr">
    </label>--%>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" formmethod="get">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is out.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Out</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Text is:</h2>
<table>
    <tr><th>Id</th><th>Headline</th><th></th></tr>
    <tr><td><%=session.getAttribute("id")%></td>
        <td><%=session.getAttribute("headline")%></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p><a href="index.jsp">Return to search</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're setting your id and headline to `request.setAttribute` and reading from `session.getAttribute`,read from `request.getAttribute`

Comment: You probably want to change the action of your form in index.jsp to call your Servlet.  Your Servlet has the db code.  Also, the conditional if(!(request.getParameter("mysql")==null))  doesn't look right. Maybe it should be if(request.getParameter("mysql") != null)

Comment: @HariHaravelan i do how you says and the resulst same null, null

Comment: @rickz i doesn`t understand what do you mean about my form

Comment: @rickz i change action to servlet action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/display" but now The requested resource [/MySQLSolrProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT/display] is not available

Comment: Did you compile your Servlet and put the class file on the classpath?

Comment: @rickz i compile my project with the artifact to .war and then deploy on tomcat.
i don`t how to send you picture there

Comment: You need to check inside Tomcat to see that your  IndexServlet.class file is placed inside of the  WEB-INF/classes folder inside of your web app.  Did Tomcat unpack your war file?

Comment: @rickz yes my IndexServlet lay in WEB-INF/classes

Comment: You could try starting over with a simple  Hello World Servlet.  You need to see that you can get a simple code to work.

Comment: @rickz i create standart java ee project with hello servlet and when i trying to press button Hello Servlet site has 404 
Message The requested resource [/demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT/hello-servlet] is not available
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
In what can be error?

Comment: Please describe your development environment.  How do you compile your Servlets?

Comment: I use maven phases first is clean to delete old .war and install to create .war, then i put it to Tomcat and start it.
My ide is Intellij Idea.
@rickz

Comment: I don't use maven or Intellij .  So, I can't help you with those.

Answer (score 0):

the error was that Tomcat version 10.* didn't want to work with version 4 servlets
I downgraded Tomcat to version 9.* and it worked.